# Laravel 5.1 route not defined redirect

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

need to ask about error, when I tried to redirect my logout

This is UserController:

```
public function logout()
{

    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('auth/login');
}
```

This is my routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Route::get('testing', 'UserController@test');
Route::get('logout', 'UserController@logout');
```

I think, taht everything is ok on routes and I defined login properly (like a Laravel documentation)

but it still take this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 306:
Route [auth/login] not defined.
```

Can you please what is wrong? Did I make any mistake?

Thanks a lot, have a nice day!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `route` method expects a name, not a URI. So you need to name your route.

Like this:

```
Route::get('auth/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin']);
```

Or:

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin')->name('login');
```

Now you can call `return redirect()->route('login');`

See the docs for [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes).

---

Alternatively, you can just provide the URI in the `redirect` method like this:

```
return redirect('auth/login');
```

Though this would break if you ever change this endpoint. I'd recommend naming your routes and using those in your code.

Answer (score 1):

change your `return redirect()->route('auth/login');` to

```
return redirect('auth/login');
```

or `return Redirect::to('auth/login');`

Comment: Thank you for additional options :)